# scraping text object in hierarchy tags by Selenium python using EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I scraped reviews from Booking.com but those reviews were mixed between positive and negative.  From the settings of booking.com, Given a user feedback, it can contain positive review, negative review, and sometime proper response from hotel as you can see in the attached figure.

[image]

My code grab all positive and negative reviews into one list but it is hard to trace back which one was positive or negative.  My expected results should be the following

```
positive_reviews = [ list of positive review ]
negative_reviews = [ list of negative review ]
proper_responses = [list of proper response ]
```

These 3 lists must have equal size.  If some feedback does not have positive review, negative review, or proper response, we will replace by None.

My original code is shown as follows.

```
import time
from random import randint
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    
name = "Eden The Residence at The Sea"

# Invoke Chrome and go to booking.com
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="./drivers/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://booking.com")
print("Accessing " + driver.title)
print(driver.current_url)

# Enter hotel name, i.e. Eden The Residence at The Sea
time.sleep(randint(1, 5))
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[class*='sb-searchbox__input']").send_keys("Eden The Residence at The Sea")

# Click search
time.sleep(randint(1, 5))
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[type='submit']").click()

# Click the hotel name, i.e. Eden the Residence at The Sea
time.sleep(randint(1, 5))
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Eden The Residence at The Sea')]").click()

# Click to show toggle side bar that store reviews
time.sleep(randint(1, 5))
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])

# Click to show all reviews
time.sleep(randint(1, 5))
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#show_reviews_tab').click()

# Retrieving reviews page by page
reviews = []
while True:
    container = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span[class='c-review__body']")))
    reviews_per_page = [container[i].text for i in range(0, len(container))]
    reviews.extend(reviews_per_page)
    
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[class='pagenext']"))).click()
    except Exception:
        driver.close()
        break
```

I'm trying to modify the first line after while loop using some hierarchy CSS tag but it does not work like this.

```
pos_container = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span[class='c-review__prefix c-review__prefix--color-green'] > 'c-review__body'")))
```

May I have your suggestions how to pass parameter of such hierarchy tags to get positive reviews, negative reviews, and proper responses separately?

Comment: Your CSS selector is invalid. Do you mean `"span.c-review__prefix.c-review__prefix--color-green ~ .c-review__body"`?

Comment: Oh!  That's right.  Now it is working.  However, When I reach to the 6th page, I got break due to time out.  If I use my previous version that cannot separate between positive and negative, It won't get break due to time out.  May I know what went wrong?

Comment: Probably there are no green reviews on page 6

Comment: Oh! I can specify the problem now.  It because all negative reviews on the 6th page were non-English and the tag is nor c-review__body but .c-review__body--original.  I do not need those non-English.  Can we specify it to pick only English?

Comment: Try to extend selector with `[lang='en']`